# Php AES encryption not working with GET

Tags: php, openssl, aes

I have written a PHP code which take list id from get request and encrypt and return. This working fine when I run from command prompt in ubuntu but giving single same output every time when I am trying it from URL request. Its also not giving single error. cant understand. Any one can help ?

```
 <?php
   if( $_GET["list"]) {
      $encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";
      $api_key ="2lYVdI37JfbUgys5kOAu";
      $encrypted = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.3') >= 0 ? openssl_encrypt($in, $encryptionMethod, $api_key, 0, '3j9hwG7uj8uvpRAT') : openssl_encrypt($in, $encryptionMethod, $api_key, 0);
      $encrypted = str_replace('/', '892', $encrypted);
      $encrypted = str_replace('+', '763', $encrypted);
      $encrypted = str_replace('=', '', $encrypted);
      echo $encrypted;

      exit();
   }
?>
```

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: `openssl_encrypt($in, ` ....you're not assigning any value to $in. So, most likely you're always getting the result for encrypting an empty string (and a warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. THanks @Volkerk.

I have assigned value and got it worked.

Thanks a Lot.